# Dictionary of integers or references key - performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary, collections

I am interested to know the difference in `Dictionary` read and write performance between using an `int` value type key and an integer wrapped into a reference type (`IntId`).

Instantiating with `int`:

```
new Dictionary<int, SomeValue>();
```

Instantiating with `IntId`:

```
new Dictionary<IntId, SomeValue>();
```

Averaged performance results yielded the following on writing and reading 200,000 items:

- `IntId` is 2X faster at writing
- `int` is 3X faster at reading

**What is the discrepancy between these two results?**

The `IntId` class:

```
public class IntId
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public IntId(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var entity = other as IntId;

        if (entity == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return (this.Value.Equals(entity.Value));
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: An easy possible explanation for the read discrepancy is that the `IntId` dictionary needs to use the class' `Equals()` method, which includes a cast and some other stuff. That could concievably slow things down.

Comment: Can you post your testing code and configuration?

Comment: Please, also try benchmark with making `IntId` a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood the discrepancy between these results will be strongly related to the method used to obtain them.

Your IntId is a small reference object. Creating one requires a memory allocation.

An integer is a value object, but may require boxing to use in your collection.

The values assigned to the keys affect the efficiency of the hashing function.

There are many factors to consider. I would not accept the results on face value until after a careful scrutiny of how they were obtained.

Comment: There is no boxing involved with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: Agreed, no boxing is _necessary_, but until we see the code we don't know what was actually tested.

Comment: Yes I was not criticizing the rest of your answer, without the details of the test, how it was setup, were the cold runs removed or included in the stats... There really isn't a better answer to provide.